# Generate excel template with more than one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which serves as a template file, that needs to generate new files according to a list of names.

How do I save them in individual folders with the same name as the file (person's name).

This is what I have:

Sub SaveMasterAs()

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim rNames As Range, c As Range, r As Range

'Current file's list of names and ids on sheet1.

Set rNames = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown))

'Path and name to master workbook to open for copy, saveas.

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template_2021.xlsm")

For Each c In rNames

With wb

.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\templates" & c.Value & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End With

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Next c

wb.Close

End Sub

Comment: I don't follow your question. The code saves several copies of the full workbook, so there shouldn't be any issues with macros or formula links.

Comment: You're right Rory! Thank so much so making me realize that. The original file must not be working very well since the generated files come with some bugs. I'll try and check that out. Many thanks!